# Ignoring all org-mode headings to export beamer slides with no titles

Tags: org-mode

I like presentation zen, where less is more. I would like to export my org-mode files as beamer slides, but have the heading title ignored so as not to position a title at the top left of the each slide.

I can do it on a per-slide basis with:

```
** My slide title
:PROPERTIES:
:BEAMER_ENV: fullframe
:END:
```

Is there a way of applying this rule to every slide, without having to add this `:PROPERTIES:` section beneath every heading in my org file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several answers were suggested on the org mode mailing list [here](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2016-04/msg00021.html).

The one solution that worked for me was to put the following line at the top of my org file:

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{}
```